# Answering Questions that should be Migrated From Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, migrated-questions

Take a question, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379157/why-is-the-year-not-displayed-in-the-questions-and-comments-dates). In this case the question has been flagged as not belonging on Stack Overflow. Is it appropriate for Stack Overflow users to answer questions like this?

**Edit**

At the time I posted this question, the question I have used as an example was on StackOverflow, it has since been migrated (which has actually served as an answer to this question ;-)

Comment: Another way to ask this questions is : should experienced users answer questions like these? is this best practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not really any problem with answering a question that should be migrated if it is still a good question. If you know the answer, you get that answer to the OP faster. The question can still be migrated, and the answer will be migrated along with it whenever that happens.

Comment: Ok Thanks @animuson, I wasnt sure

Comment: Please see edit in my question

Comment: @Yve Yes, I'm aware, I migrated it. ;)

Comment: that's funny, can I ask, I flagged it, does my flag count towards migrating it? in the comments, it showed it needed another flag to migrate, or is that different, does it need votes to migrate?

Comment: @Yve Your flag gets dismissed as helpful the moment another user (any user) casts an actual close vote on the question.

Comment: what do you mean dismissed? not helpful, or passed over

Comment: @Yve "dismissed as helpful" - meaning it's marked as helpful.