# Why is the year NOT displayed in the questions and comments dates?

Tags: discussion, timestamps, dates

Why is it that the year is never displayed in the questions or comments? Is it because it is the current year? I, and maybe others, wonder.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's because it's the current year.

Otherwise it would look [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823/suggestions-for-implementing-audit-tables-in-sql-server):

> [image]

Comment: I saw you were waiting on another flag to migrate, would my flag to migrate count, as a lower rep user?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189290/answering-questions-that-should-be-migrated-from-stack-overflow

Comment: -1 for not providing freehand circle :(

Comment: @hims056 Fixed :p

Comment: As an aside: for lists, such as search results, it's something like the year is printed if the post is more than xx days old. For example, [right now](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A2012-08-20..2012-08-21) one might see ["aug 20 '12" *with* a year, and "aug 21" *without* a year](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eU7HR.png).